# Django and elasticsearch, search results are not highlighted

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I have implemented the blog using, django and elasticsearch, it works correctly as I expect, but I want the search results that match to be highlighted with bold and the below is my implementation but does not seem to work, I need help.

```py
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    posts = []
    if query:
        q = Q('multi_match', query=query, fields=['title', 'body'], fuzziness='auto')
        search = Search().query(q)
        search = search.highlight('title', 'body')
        search = search.highlight_options(pre_tags='<b>', post_tags='</b>')
        hits = search.execute()
        for hit in hits:
            postId = hit.meta.id
            postById = Post.published.get(id=postId)
            highlight = hit.meta.highlight.to_dict().get(postId, {}).get('title', '') 
            highlightBody = hit.meta.highlight.to_dict().get(postId, {}).get('body', '') 
            post = {
                'title': hit.title,
                'body': hit.body,
                'link': postById.get_absolute_url(),
                'highlight': highlight,
                'highlightBody': highlightBody,
            }
            posts.append(post)
            
    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'posts': posts, 'query':query})
```

and in my template I accessed the variable like:-`{{post.highlightBody|default:post.body}}`

Comment: please print the result of `hit.meta.highlight.to_dict()`...

Comment: the `.to_dict()` should *at least* print an empty dictionary... It is not about the rest of the [*"train wreck"*](https://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck) :)

Comment: It prints the match results like `{'title': ['data'], 'body': ['data']}`

Comment: then you likely should use: `hit.meta.highlight.to_dict().get('title', '')`?

Comment: I get problem on template rendering `'list' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: Well you will indeed have to post-process it to join the list items to a single string.